# JComboBox.setEditable(true) not changing value inside JTable

Tags: java, swing

I put JComboBox inside JTable and setEditable(true)...well it works fine when I change the values from the list, but when I write a new value and try to change it the value is not changing.
I thought it's my bug and loaded a sample code of JTable handle JCombobox from sun site...again set it to Editable true but got the same results.
here is a code sample

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Set up column sizes.
        initColumnSizes(table);

        //Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /*
     * This method picks good column sizes.
     * If all column heads are wider than the column's cells'
     * contents, then you can just use column.sizeWidthToFit().
     */
    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
            table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);

        comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                             null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                             false, false, 0, 0);
        headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Initializing width of column . "
                               + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth
                               + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
        }

        column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table,
                                 TableColumn sportColumn) {
        //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
        comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox.addItem("Pool");
        comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        comboBox.setEditable(true);

        //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
                new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Sport"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"Snowboarding"},{"Rowing"},{"Knitting"},{"Speed reading"},{"Pool"}};


        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
           return true;
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what to do ??????

Comment: does anyone know the answer for this issue ?????

Comment: Can someone tell me, is it a bug ??????

Comment: Still no answer, can someone tell me how to put the question again on the to of the list?